# Sort list of nested lists based on nested date objects

Tags: python, list, date, sorting, nested

*(I know the answer is out there somewhere already, but I have not programmed in a while and I am pressed for time. I apologize. The question will be deleted afterwards.)*

**What is the most efficient way to sort the nested lists (`user_data`) from oldest to newest or vice-versa based on their date objects (`follow_date`)?**

```
for web_element in web_elements:
  user_data = web_element.text
  follow_date = web_element.find_element(By.XPATH, './parent::div/following-sibling::div').text
  follow_date = datetime.strptime(follow_date, '%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
  user_data = [datetime.strftime(follow_date, '%b %d at %I:%M %p'), user_data]
  data['key'].append(user_data)
```

I know it would probably be more efficient to sort the list ***as*** I am building it as opposed to sorting the list ***after*** building it, but maximum efficiency, although ideal, is not absolutely necessary.

Might have found an adequate solution:

```
data['key'].sort(key = lambda date: datetime.strptime(date[0], '%b %d at %I:%M %p'))
```

That said, I am still interested in knowing the most efficient algorithm for this purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

i think that the most efficient way is to use built in functions just as you did but in case you want to more efficiency why don't you use a data structure like tree it would be easy and efficient

Comment: it is not necessarily efficiency that i was looking for. i just needed a solution quickly. however, im still interested in which algorithm/way of sorting is, technically speaking, most efficient out of sheer curiosity :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).